# Font consistency with Excel graphics

Tags: graphics, graphs, excel, pdfcrop

I am using Excel to create graphs to then include in my document.
The workflow is as follows:

1. Create Graph in excel, adjust width to same width as found from `\textwidth`, set font to "Book Antiqua" and size 11
2. Save Graph as pdf
3. Crop pdf using pdfcrop
4. Include in my document using `\includegraphics`  (without the width option)

I am using font size 11pt and `\usepackage{palatino}` in my document.

However the size of the text in my graphs is different (larger) then in the rest of my document.

Any suggestions on where I am going wrong?

Comment: Font sizes are not consistent across fonts.  If you'd used exactly the same font and don't rescale the image then the sizes should be the same.  (I know that they're close.)

Comment: As an aside, have a look at pgfplots (and tikz!).  You avoid such headaches altogether and can avoid the garish graphs produced by Excel.

Comment: Wow thanks for the very quick response @JPi. Is there a way to obtain the "original" Palatino font as used in my LaTeX document for Windows/Office? Otherwise can you recommend another similar font which exists in both environments?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a font expert, but there are many such experts on this forum.